# Dokku deployed Rails site does not rewrite SCSS images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dokku, buildpack

I'm using Dokku to deploy a RoR site, using the Herokuish Ruby [buildpack](https://github.com/gliderlabs/herokuish/tree/master/buildpacks/buildpack-ruby).

There are no errors when I deploy: (though the time does seem quite short)

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Asset precompilation completed (3.58s)
       Cleaning assets
```

The asset filenames are being fingerprinted correctly and the images used in the views having their paths rewritten as expected.

However, despite the fact that I'm using `background-image: url(image_path('parallax/masthead.jpg'));` in the SCSS, the URLs are not being rewritten.

Here are the relevant lines from my config/production.rb

```
config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
```

In my Gemfile I have:

```
group :production do
  gem 'puma', '~> 2.15.3'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

I tried running `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` locally and it worked, with both the views and CSS being rewritten correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I've found it - in the SCSS file I had:

```
background: url(image_path('layout/opacity.png')) repeat;
```

which for some reason was causing it to fail. Changing it to:

```
background-image: url(image_path('layout/opacity.png'));
background-repeat: repeat;
```

sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite `background-image: url(image_path('parallax/masthead.jpg'));` to

```
background-image: image-url('parallax/masthead.jpg');
```

Comment: Oh wow, that actually worked!

What's REALLY strange is that I just changed the first one (as above) to test it but after I did that the rest of them started working - so now I really don't understand what I was doing wrong...

Comment: Hmm...that's weird, but in original docs they said to use: `image-url` and some other options, you can look at section **2.3.2 CSS and Sass** on this link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets